# Display MYSQL SUM data per date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that I want to sum the values of, but I have a problem that I don't know how to solve that is how can I keep displaying the same code with different date periods

**below is the table I have:**

| p_code | k_code | score | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | K001 | 20 | 2021-12-30 |
| P001 | K002 | 10 | 2021-12-30 |
| P002 | K003 | 15 | 2021-12-30 |
| P001 | K004 | 25 | 2022-06-01 |
| P001 | K005 | 15 | 2022-06-01 |
| P003 | K006 | 10 | 2022-06-01 |
| P003 | K007 | 25 | 2022-06-01 |

**I want output like this:**

| p_code | total_score | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | 30 | 2021-12-30 |
| P002 | 15 | 2021-12-30 |
| P001 | 40 | 2022-06-01 |
| P003 | 35 | 2022-06-01 |

I have tried this way:

```
SELECT p_code, SUM(score) AS total_score, date FROM my_table GROUP BY p_code
```

but i know it's not the right way

please any one help me out to write the query in triggers. any one help me out ......

Comment: For the first part of your question include date in select and group by. For the second part why a trigger and what kind of trigger?(insert,update,delete)

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you're carrying out an aggregation, you need to group on all the fields you're not aggregating on inside the `SELECT` statement, namely "*p_code*" and "*date*". Your query should become as follows:

```
SELECT p_code, 
       SUM(score) AS total_score, 
       date 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY p_code, 
         date
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oohL5AmKExr1HecBbSiAwb/0).

Note: Triggers should not be employed when you're just selecting values from your tables, instead you should consider such tool when your either inserting, deleting or updating your table.